# In External directory folder is not created in Android 8.0 but it is working in 6.0 and 7.0 devices when target SDK version is 26

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, android-file

The folder directory is not created `External storage` in the Android 8.0 devices, but it is working in 6.0 and 7.0 devices.  I am always getting

> "Unable to create App directory error"

. When the app target version is 26. If i put the target version is <=25, it is creating a folder in the `external storage` in all android devices including 8.0.

```
    File appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + fileName);
    try {
        if (!appDirectory.exists() && !appDirectory.mkdir()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unable to create App Directory for: " + fileName + " File");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> `"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` permission is added in Manifest file.

Comment: have you created file provider?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar solutions here: [Android 8.1 - Problem trying to create directory in external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474210/android-8-1-problem-trying-to-create-directory-in-external-storage)

From Android 6.0 up to latest, requesting deep permission needs to manually code it not just provide it in Manifest. There's nothing wrong with your code. Here's to prove: In your android device, go to Settings>>Apps>>Your App>>Permissions>>Allow the external storage permission. And your app will work, try it. (But other users must do this also) So here's how to code it without going to settings:

Inside onCreate, put this.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
{
Manifest.Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
Manifest.Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
//other permissions you like to add
},1);
}
```

It should work by now.